# URL query parameters are not processed in django rest

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

Here is my `views.py`:

```
class my4appCompanyData(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = my4appSerializer

    def get_queryset(self,request):
        """Optionally restricts the returned data to ofa company,
        by filtering against a `id` query parameter in the URL. """
        queryset = companies_csrhub.objects.all()
        #url_id = self.request.query_params.get('id', None)
        url_id = request.GET.get('id', None)
        if id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(id=url_id)
        elif id is ALL:
            queryset = companies_csrhub.objects.all()
        else:
            queryset = "Error data not found"
        return queryset
```

And my `urls.py`:

```
router.register(r'api/my4app/company/$', views.my4appCompanyData.as_view(),base_name="company")
```

URL used for checking: `mywebsite/api/my4app/company/?id=100227`

Planning to add multiple filters with default values but not working. Please help.

Comment: You return in the middle of that method.

Answer (score 0):

```
class my4appCompanyData(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = my4appSerializer

    def get_queryset(self,request):
        """Optionally restricts the returned data to ofa company,
        by filtering against a `id` query parameter in the URL. """
        queryset = companies_csrhub.objects.all()
        url_id = request.query_params.get('id', None)
        if id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(id=url_id)
        elif id is ALL:
            queryset = companies_csrhub.objects.all()
        else:
            queryset = []
        return queryset
```

Delete the return id since id is not a queryset, therefore it'd give an error. Also in the else part of if statement, you return string but you can't do that also since string is not a queryset.

Comment: Sorry that return id was just a typo while checking but with out that also the result is same {detail : not found}. But when i hard code the same value in filter it works. I need a way to access key value pair style parameters from the url.

Comment: Is there a way to debug line by line in django and see what is the vakue set for the parameters ? Or suggest a better method. This wold be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure but can you do that after getting url_id?    url_id = int(url_id)

Comment: For debug use pdb.

Answer (score 0):

According the official docs (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters)

I think your code is not working because you are using:

```
url_id = request.query_params.get('id', None)
```

Instead of:

```
url_id = self.request.query_params.get('id', None)
```

In the documentation you can find that get_queryset function just receives `self` param, you must remove `request` param.

Comment: Tried url_id=self.request.get('id', None) not working.